# I want to make purposely 5%, 10%, of the values in the dataframe to be replaced by NAs to simulate random missing data

Tags: r

I have a complete dataframe of 4 years monthly rainfall data. I want to make purposely 5%, 10%, 20%, 30% and 40% of the values in the dataframe to be replaced by NAs to simulate random missing data. How I can do it in R or excel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

We would usually ask for some example data and an indication of what approaches you have tried so far. But to get you started, here's one approach using `dplyr`.

Let's make some fake data with 4 years, 12 months per year and 1 observation per month, so 48 rows total:

```
set.seed(1001) # for reproducibility
raindata <- data.frame(Year  = rep(2000:2003, each = 12),
                       Month = rep(month.name, 4),
                       Rain  = sample(0:100, 48, replace = TRUE),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`dplyr` has a function `sample_frac()`, which will sample a given fraction of rows. For example, to sample 95% of them:

```
library(dplyr)
raindata %>%
  sample_frac(0.95)
```

Then you can `inner_join` the sampled rows to the original data - but only join on Year and Month. This will give you two `Rain` columns: `Rain.y` (the original) and `Rain.x`, containing 5% NA values because only `Year` and `Month` were matched,  not `Rain`:

```
raindata_new <- raindata %>% 
  sample_frac(0.95) %>%
  right_join(raindata, 
             by = c("Year", "Month"))
```

For 10%, 20%, 30% and 40% just replace the value in `sample_frac()` with 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 and 0.6, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce NAs not only in one column, but over the whole data.frame (even your identifying / key columns), then the following appoach will work.

Lets take the sample data from the first answer and add another column "Pressure".

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(1001) 


raindata <- data.frame(Year  = rep(2000:2003, each = 12),
                       Month = rep(month.name, 4),
                       Rain  = sample(0:100, 48, replace = TRUE),
                       Pressure = sample(900:1100, 48, replace = TRUE),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now you can create a data.frame with a given percentage of TRUE / FALSEs and in a next step you can loop over the columns with an if_else statement to replace FALSE with NA.

```
na_df <- matrix(data = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),
                              size = length(as.matrix(raindata)),
                              replace = TRUE,
                              prob = c(0.9,0.1)), # Here you can adjust the probability
                nrow = nrow(raindata),
                ncol = ncol(raindata),
                dimnames = list(rownames(raindata),
                                colnames(raindata))) %>% as.data.frame()

map2_df(raindata, na_df, function(x,y) ifelse(y == TRUE, x, NA))
```